# Visual Basic 6.0 FileListBox

Tags: vba

How do I show only specific file types in the file list box?  For example, show all .docx files from the whole computer directories.  I would also want people to choose from the files listed in the "File list box" and open it through a command button.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at this and update your question accordingly http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

The FileListBox has  "Pattern" property. Enter *.docx there.
Also: add a DirListBox and a DriveListBox too.

```
Private Sub Drive1_Change()
Dir1.Path=Drive1.Drive
End Sub

Private Sub Dir1_Change()
File1.Path=Dir1.Path
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I show all the *.docx files that has been saved all over my computer?

Comment: Do you know anytrhing about VB6? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know some basic stuff, haven't really tried exploring it that much.  Thanks for answering, definitely would helped me a lot.